# vertical scroll bar show incorrectly

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

[image]

i have set the style as overflow-x: scroll; and overflow-y: visible; in parentNode, in this scenario only will show the horizontal scroll bar in my output... but both scroll-bar will be appear in my output (since parentNode height > childNode height).what i made wrong? how to resolve this?

here is my code,

```
<div id="chartContainer_container" style="position: relative;">
       <div style="position: absolute; width: 63px; height: 52px;left: 230px; top: 110px; overflow-x: scroll; overflow-y: visible;border-width: 1px; border-color: 'black'; border-style: solid;" id="legend_container">
            <svg style="height: 37px; width: 139px;" class="e-designerhide" id="legend_container_svg">
                    <g id="container_svg_Legend">
                        <g cursor="pointer" id="container_svg_Legend0">
                            <path lgndctx="true" d="M 9 16.5 L 12 16.5 L 12 23.5 L 9 23.5 Z M 13.5 11 L 16.5 11 L 16.5 23.5 L 13.5 23.5 Z M 18 18.5 L 21 18.5 L 21 23.5 L 18 23.5 Z" opacity="1" stroke="transparent" stroke-width="1" fill="#77A7FB" id="container_svg_LegendItemShape0"></path>
                            <text lgndctx="true" text-anchor="start" font-weight="Regular" font-family="Segoe UI" font-style="Normal" font-size="12" fill="#636363" y="22.75" x="30" id="container_svg_LegendItemText0">SumofBugCount</text>
                        </g>
                    </g>
            </svg>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Sample Link : https://jsfiddle.net/xq7kdx6o/

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SVG's size:

```
element.style {
    height: 37px;
    width: 139px;
}
```

Which is greater than parent:

```
width: 63px;
height: 52px;
```

Try parent's width as `140px`. And you have this style on the parent:

```
overflow-x: scroll;
overflow-y: visible;
```

You need to use:

```
<div style="position: absolute; width: 140px; height: 52px;left: 230px; top: 110px; border-width: 1px; border-color: 'black'; border-style: solid;" id="legend_container">
```

Seriously? Is the parent smaller?

[image]

**Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xq7kdx6o/1/**

If you just want the vertical scroll not come, use `overflow-y: hidden`.

**Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xq7kdx6o/2/**

Comment: i need to show to horizontal scrollbar.. without change the height and width

Comment: @AkbarBasha If you just want the vertical scroll not come, use `overflow-y: hidden`. https://jsfiddle.net/xq7kdx6o/2/